# assigning custom label to spacy using pandas dataframe

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am new to NLP based programming. I am trying to compare a word to an exisiting dataset using NLP.

I have a dataframe as shown below

[image: dataframe]

Now, I have an input text like " krish Stockholm" the program should tag each word to the column label of the trained dataset and display as shown below

krish: Name

Stockholm : City

Can it be done using spacy ? Appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spacy` to recognize person names & locations, your input string might always not return the entities, for example in case the string has only `'krish Stockholm'` text it might identify it as name only, so the quality of input text will be crucial.

You can update values to an existing dataframe like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
sentence = "Tom works in Apple office at California"
doc = nlp(sentence) 

mylist= []
for ent in doc.ents: 
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
    mylist.append([ent.text,ent.label_])

print(mylist)

[['Tom', 'PERSON'], ['Apple', 'ORG'], ['California', 'GPE']]

person = ', '.join([i[0] for i in mylist if i[1] == 'PERSON'])
location = ', '.join([i[0] for i in mylist if i[1] == 'GPE'])

df = df.append({'Name':person,'City':location}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

    Name   Age        City
0    Tom  20.0  California
1   nick  21.0    Brussels
2  krish  19.0   Stockholm
3   jack  18.0       Delhi
4    Tom   NaN  California
```

But if you change `'A'` in `Apple` to `'a'` then it will no longer recognize `Apple` as an organization.

Comment: Thank you Manoj. I am looking for a way to achieve the below functionality.

Can I train the values in the dataframe so that any prediction of an input string would get me the column name of the dataframe?

for eg : " krish Stockholm" should get me the column names of the dataframe

krish should return 'Name'
and  Stockholm should return 'City' based on the training

Comment: You want to use Spacy trained model or want to train a model with your own data? I have mentioned the method which you can use with Spacy. Making predictions using your own training data will be a difficult task as you need to cover millions of names.

Comment: Manoj, Yeah. I have my requirement posted in the link.If you could advice any possibility of achiving he same may be through other techniques, would highly appreciate that. Thanks again

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045175/fetching-related-records-from-data-set-using-nlp